# Android Sqlite - Select the row which was inserted 1 hour before

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

Am working on Android Sqlite where I try to fetch the rows which are inserted 1 hour before.But its not returning any thing,I checked by cursor.count()

I tried with the following queries

```
String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_CONTENT1, KEY_CONTENT2,
                KEY_CONTENT3, KEY_CONTENT4, KEY_CONTENT5, KEY_CONTENT6};

cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_CONTENT3               + "< " + "DATETIME('NOW', '-1 hours')", null, null, null, null);
```

AND another query

```
String selectRow = "select *  FROM detail1 WHERE content3 < DATETIME('NOW', '-1 hours');";

Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(selectRow);
```

AND another query

```
String selectRow = "select *  FROM detail1 WHERE content3 < DATETIME('NOW', '-1 hours');";

cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(selectRow,null);
```

This Query Works for me

```
String selectRow = "select *  FROM detail1 WHERE content3 > DATETIME('NOW', '-1 hours');";

Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(selectRow);
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "1 hour before"? Your queries return any records that were inserted *more* than one hour before.

Comment: The records which are inserted 1 hour before,My above Query doesn't return any records.

Comment: You are just repeating what you wrote in the question. Please edit your question to show an example of the current time, and what records should and should not be returned.

Comment: I edited Please check is it okay

Answer (score 0):

```
DATETIME('NOW', '-1 hours');"
```

This function returns time in this 2014-01-04,
    and in data base `2014-01-04 10:24:21` have in this format. here only `2014` is getting compared not the complete date. better approch i would suggest go with epoch

try below query which will give you difference in terms of seconds

`SELECT (strftime('%s','now')/60) - (strftime('%s',content3)/60);`

Comment: Can you please suggest me with any query

Comment: i want to retrieve in terms of hour, ANd the fuction DATETIME('Now','-1hours');works well while deleting a record  1 hour before.

Comment: even i had same issue, after spending complete day took alternative way,check my update

Comment: Its returning null,But i want the rows which is inserted 1 hour before.

Comment: Query Error: no such column: content3 Unable to execute statement

Comment: try to put ur proper colum name